# Key value pair in Java from JSON file

Tags: java, json

I have an JSON data

```
{
"HiServiceInquiryResponse": {
    "CoverageInfoResponse": {
        "Participant": {
            "ns1:PersonalInfo": {
                "ns1:LastName": "AA",
                "ns1:Address": [
                    {
                        "ns1:Province": "",
                        "ns1:State": "CA",
                        "ns1:City": "LOS ANGELES",
                        "ns1:Country": "US",
                        "ns1:Address2": "",
                        "ns1:Address1": "test",
                        "ns1:PostalCode": 12345
                    },
                    {
                        "ns1:Province": "",
                        "ns1:State": "CA",
                        "ns1:City": "LOS ANGELES",
                        "ns1:Country": "US",
                        "ns1:Address2": "",
                        "ns1:Address1": "test",
                        "ns1:PostalCode": 12345
                    }
                ],
                "ns1:FirstName": "BB"
            },
            "ns1:Coverage": "",
            "ns1:HiClientId": 57,
            "ns1:Employment": {
                "ns1:EmployeeId": 1234,
                "ns1:TaxId": 111
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I want to read all the key-value pairs and store them. So far I am able to do  it

```
    public static void printJsonObject(JSONObject jsonObj) {

    for (Object key : jsonObj.keySet()) {
        String keyStr = (String) key;
        Object keyvalue = jsonObj.get(keyStr);

        if (!(keyvalue instanceof JSONObject)) {
            System.out.println(keyStr + ", " + keyvalue);
        }
        if (keyvalue instanceof JSONObject) {
            printJsonObject((JSONObject) keyvalue);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when we have 2 address in the personalInfo it does not read them separately.

My Output when there is only 1 address: ->

```
    ns1:LastName, AA
    ns1:Province, 
    ns1:State, CA
    ns1:City, LOS ANGELES
    ns1:Country, US
    ns1:Address2, 
    ns1:Address1, test
    ns1:PostalCode, 12345
    ns1:FirstName, BB
    ns1:Coverage, 
    ns1:HiClientId, 57
    ns1:EmployeeId, 1234
    ns1:TaxId, 111
```

My Output when there are 2 address: ->

```
    ns1:LastName, AA
    ns1:Address, [{"ns1:Province":"","ns1:State":"CA","ns1:City":"LOS ANGELES","ns1:Country":"US","ns1:Address2":"","ns1:Address1":"test","ns1:PostalCode":12345},{"ns1:Province":"","ns1:State":"CA","ns1:City":"LOS ANGELES","ns1:Country":"US","ns1:Address2":"","ns1:Address1":"test","ns1:PostalCode":12345}]
    ns1:FirstName, BB
    ns1:Coverage, 
    ns1:HiClientId, 57
    ns1:EmployeeId, 1234
    ns1:TaxId, 111
```

I want the data should be displayed for both addresses.

Comment: Consider using Jackson.  Nothing homegrown will ever be better than an existing, well tested product.

Comment: I was not able to do so using Jackson, I am new to java

Comment: Can it print the data in the order it is coming?

Comment: Json is order independent.  It should not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should solve your problem

```
public static void printJsonObject(JSONObject jsonObj) {

        for (Object key : jsonObj.keySet()) {
            String keyStr = (String) key;
            Object keyvalue = jsonObj.get(keyStr);

            if (keyvalue instanceof JSONObject) {
                printJsonObject((JSONObject) keyvalue);
            } else if (keyvalue instanceof JSONArray) {
                JSONArray array = (JSONArray) keyvalue;
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    printJsonObject((JSONObject) array.get(i));
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println(keyStr + ", " + keyvalue);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works like a charm. !

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

Should be size()

Comment: Can it print the data in the order it is coming?

Answer (score 2):

To parse array inside `JSONObject` you have to check value instance of `JSONArray` and recursively call `printJsonObject` for each array item:

```
public static void printJsonObject(JSONObject jsonObj) {
    for (Object key : jsonObj.keySet()) {
        Object value = jsonObj.get(key);

        if (value instanceof JSONObject)
            printJsonObject((JSONObject)value);
        else if (value instanceof JSONArray)
            ((JSONArray)value).forEach(obj -> printJsonObject((JSONObject)obj));
        else
            System.out.println(key + ", " + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can it print the data in the order it is coming?

Comment: Yes. It saves order of the values.

Answer (score 0):

change your code as

```
  if (!(keyvalue instanceof JSONObject)) {

    if(keyStr.equals("ns1:Address")){

        //now it is your array so loop through it and call printJsonObject((JSONObject) keyvalue); on each object

    }
    else{
        System.out.println(keyStr + ", " + keyvalue);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when there are two addresses, the JSONObject corresponding to the address is an array. If you want it to be printed separately, check whether it is an instanceOf JSONArray. Then parse through the different addresses in the array. If it is not an array, just print it.